# No reloading modification Python Class with Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm working with Jupyter for compiling code. I have created a set of different .py script creating the class for each script.
Basically, I have the script my_class.py which includes

```
  def functional_feed(self):
    a=5
    return a
```

Now in Jupyter I'm using:

```
from f.rel import my_class
gre= my_class.functional_feed()
```

and it works with 5.
But if I change something in my_class and within functional_feed, for instance, the def becomes:

```
 def functional_feed(self):
  a=11
  return a
```

and try to compile again within jupiter, all the changes have not effect and it returns 5.

Why?

thank you in advance

Comment: I think that you must restart the kernel of the notebook where you import the class.

Answer (score 1):

Python caches imports by default, so you have to reload the import:

```py
import f.rel
import importlib
# clear the import cache
importlib.reload(f.rel)
# now you can import my_class and it'll be updated
from f.rel import my_class
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your reply. I don't know why, but it doesn't reload the script. If I delete the content from  my_class.py, and reload as you suggested it returns always 5.

Comment: could it happen due to the colab environment?